# Identity element of a group as a factorization of group elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For any group $G$ we readily verify that if $a,b,c\in G$ and $a*b*c=e$ , where $e$ denotes the identity element,then also: $b*c*a=e$

Indeed,let $b*c=x$.Then our problem amounts to: $a*x=e⇒x*a=e$ This is almost direct,but let's be thorough:

$a*x=e ⇒x=a^{-1}⇒e=x^{-1}*a^{-1}⇒a=x^{-1}⇒x*a=e$ and we are done.

What happens though if we take another factorization of more than 3 elements,and particularly,the general case where $a_1*a_2*...*a_n=e$ and $σ$ is a permutation of the $a_i$ elements? Can we describe the cases in which it holds that: $a_{σ(1)}*a_{σ(2)}*...*a_{σ(ν)}=e$?

If the permutation is such that: $σ(a_1*a_2*...*a_n)=a_n*(a_1'*a_2'*..*a_{n-1}')$ or $σ(a_1*a_2*...*a_n)=(a_1'*a_2'*..*a_{n-1}')*a_n$, the same approach as before applies,but more generally?

Comment: More generally it does not apply. It is easy to find three invertible $2\times 2$-matrices $A,B,C$ such that $ABC = I_3$ but $CBA \neq I_3$.

Comment: I think, but really I am not sure, it will work exactly for the cyclic permutations.

Comment: @darijgrinberg But by the general case I do not refer to that.I seek to find if I can describe the case when for a number of elements that it does hold $a_1*a_2*...*a_n=e⇒σ(a_{1'}*a_{2'}*...a_{n'})=e$ what properties-If any-the group has? How can we describe it..

Comment: @quid: Yes, it works exactly for the cyclic permutations. That it works for cyclic permutations is clear. That it doesn't work for any other permutation follows from setting $a_1 = x_1$, $a_2 = x_2$, ..., $a_{n-1} = x_{n-1}$ and $a_n = x_{n-1}^{-1} x_{n-2}^{-1} \cdots x_1^{-1}$ in a free group with $n-1$ generators $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}$, and recalling that each element of a free group has a unique normal form as a word in the generators and their inverses such that no generator stands adjacent to its inverse.

Comment: @JDrinas: A group in which every three elements $a,b,c$ satisfying $abc=e$ must satisfy $cba=e$ is abelian. Do you see how to prove this? I suspect that something like this holds for any permutation $\sigma$ which is not cyclic, though I don't have a proof.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes,that is pretty clear..Perhaps I will disappoint you but my knowledge is not that extensive-still being a pregrad student:-).Thanks for the insights though!